Is there any way to manage pagination manually in Jetpack compose?
I have been struggling for days watching tutorials and reading documentations related to pagination in Jetpack using the Paging 3 library and I find it quite confusing and difficult to understand. Is there any way to manage pagination manually in jetpack compose?

Yes you can consider using lazy list and call api for getting next page data when last visible item is equivalent to last item in the list. Provided - your api manages call such that you pass start, end and page count parameter and it returns responnse accordingly.

Paging is three distinct layers: the data source (which, if you're using something like Room, is done for you), a Pager in your ViewModel, and the Compose UI integration. Was it the Compose UI part that was where you got stuck? The documentation is actually almost the entirety of the code you need.

I don't even know where the problem is, but what I see is just a loading screen then the app crashes without any errors in the logcat

Apps never crash without an exception in logcat

You are right, that was my fault, I was applying a filter
